# Calling a function within a Class other then default index()?

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I have a class like,

```
class test
{

  public function index()
  {

  }

  public function home()
  {

  }

}
```

but when i call my class like,

```
$test = new test();
```

It will execute the default function index(), my question is how can i call the function home() and ignore the function index()?

I tried to call the function after making the object of class like $test->home() but it still call the index() first and then call the home().

A little help or direction will be appreciated,

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: `index()` doesn't get called! Also if you call `home()` `index()` also doesn't get called! I think you are not showing the right code!

Comment: PHP does not call `index()` on its own when you instantiate a class. There must be something else calling this method in your code. [PHP Constructors/destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) manual. If you say that `index()` is called when you instantiate the class, then it **must** be called from the class' `__construct()` method.

Comment: yes, one change - in actual i named the class index also, it that the reason??

Comment: @AliNawazHiraj Yes this is why! Also you shouldn't do that, exactly because if that(IT's the constructor then)! (BTW: If you call home, index still doesn't get called!)

Comment: PHP allows you to have a constructor function named as your class. In that case, PHP **will** automatically call the function when you instantiate the class.

Comment: I see, but is there anyway to stop index() being called? I saw codeigniter do that even if we named the it's controller with index, still we able to call the other functions without calling the default index(). Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @AliNawazHiraj Yes you can add the magic method `__construct()` like this: `public function __construct()` So that this is the constructor and it get's called. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot Rizier!!! I got it, Perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that with adding the magic method `__construct()` like this:

```
<?php

    class index {

        public function __construct() {
            echo "1";
        }

        public function index() {
            echo "2";
        }

        public function home() {
            echo "3";
        }

    }

    $obj = new index();
    $obj->index();
    $obj->home();

?>
```

Output:

```
123
```

As you can see every method is called as you want

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those functions will be called when the class is instantiated. The function that is called when instantiating is `__construct()`.

So, if you'd like to just call `home()` on instantiating the class, use the following function in your class.

```
function __construct() {
    $this->home();
}
```

Instantiating the class will call `__construct()`, which will in turn call `home()`.